# Android java back to activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my app I wrote mechanism which lets return to the activity whet the application is suddenly removed from the device memory. Sometimes it happens eg. when  the phone rings and there is not enough memory for phone application and my app. After the phone app ends the system call quite new process for my app and opens this activity which was closed previously.
I hope the mechanism I wrote works fine but I don’t know how to test it. I work in android studio.

So the question is how to simulate the process of killing and removal the application from system, and calling back my app process and activity.

Comment: Sending broadcasts with adb commands? The effort of my comment matches the quality of the question

Comment: If I knew the answer I would not ask. What command should I ran?

Answer (score 0):

fire this by cmd

echo 'am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n "package name/path of reciver" --es "referrer" "utm_source=test_source&utm_medium=test_medium&utm_term=test_term&utm_content=test_content&utm_campaign=test_name"; exit' | ./adb shell